# Emptying the contents of a named Pipe

Tags: c#, pipe, buffer, ipc

In my `C#` application, I have a named pipe. The server starts up, and waits for a client to connect and write something in the pipe, i.e.,the client is expected to write.

I am not able to clear the `NamedPipe` of any of its contents after reading from the server. I want to clear the content of the named pipe after each read, but the `Flush()` does not seem to work.

Separately, if any other client connected to the NamedPipe and writes something, whatever is written does not make it to the server, which keeps on reading the same string written by the first client.

**EDIT - Some code**

```
public delegate void EventHandler();
class someClass
{
    WrapperForm dlg = null;
    public void CallToChildThread(Object stateInfo)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
        if (server.IsConnected)
        {
            string tempString = reader.ReadLine();
            server.Flush();
        //Fire event
          _show.Invoke();
        }
    public someClass()
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream server;
        public static event EventHandler _show;
        server = new NamedPipeServerStream("TagCnfConnection", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
        server.WaitForConnectionAsync();
        initializeDialog(); // Initialize the dialog. Standard new
        var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var stateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(CallToChildThread,
                                   autoEvent, 1000, 250);
        _show += new EventHandler(eventCheck);
    }
    void eventCheck()
    {
        //If some condition
        dlg.ShowDialog(); //Timer stops
    }
}
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: got a minimal viable bit of code we can play with ?

Comment: I've added some code. Kindly advise if I'm missing something.

Comment: You wrote that the server reads only from the first client, does this have to do with the fact that in the NamedPipeServerStream ctor you specified only 1 instance?